# Establishing the connection using UDP and TCP socket programming in c

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to establish the UDP and TCP connection in same code. I have 3 programs with the source in `server.c`, `transfer.c` and `client.c`. I want first `server` to run and wait for data; then `transfer` and then `client`.

My desired result is that, if I type message in `client`, it sends to `transfer` using TCP, and `transfer` forwards this message to the server using TCP. When `server` receives the message, it will check the message whether it's alpha or digit. If it is alpha, `server` sends "This is not digit" message to the `client` using UDP. If it is a digit, it just forwards the same message to `client` using UDP.

I was able to send message using TCP to the `server` and then I couldn't send a specific message to the `client` using UDP.  Any idea what's wrong?

Here is my code.  This is my `server.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>      
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define PORTNUM 2400
#define MAXRCVLEN 500
#define SERVER "127.0.0.1" // local server
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 2500   //The port to establish UDP conection

void DieWithError(char *s)
{
perror(s);
exit(1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char* msg = "HI \n"; 
char buffer[MAXRCVLEN + 1];

int len, consocket;
struct sockaddr_in dest;
struct sockaddr_in serv;
int mysocket;
socklen_t socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));
serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//UDP initialiazation to forward received message to client
struct sockaddr_in si_other;
int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other), recv_len;
char buf[BUFLEN];
char message[BUFLEN];
int num; //number of messages   

s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

//creates socket
memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);

inet_aton(SERVER , &si_other.sin_addr);


    /*{
        DieWithError("sendto() failed");
    }*/


 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

do{
listen(mysocket, 1);
consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
send(consocket, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
    while(len=recv(consocket, buffer, MAXRCVLEN, 0)>0){
            if(strncmp(buffer, "exit", 4) == 0){ 
        break;
    }

           printf("Received: %s ", buffer);
         //checks the received message alpha or digit
            if(isalpha(buf[0])){
        strcpy(buf, "this is not a digit");//sends this message to client 
        //if the message is alphs
        }



           //udp sends function to send the msg using UDP
            if (sendto(s, message, strlen(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr
   *) &si_other, slen)==-1)
    {
        DieWithError("sendto() failed");
    }
    //clear the buffer
    memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
  //memset(buffer, 0, strlen(buffer));


    }
  printf("Goodbye !\n");
    close(consocket);

}while(consocket);

close(mysocket);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is my `transfer.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define PORTNUM1 2300
#define PORTNUM2 2400
#define MAXRCVLEN 500


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char* msg = "HI from Inter-server\n"; 
char buffer[MAXRCVLEN + 1];

int len, consocket;
struct sockaddr_in dest;
struct sockaddr_in serv;

struct sockaddr_in client;

int server_socket;
int client_socket;

// For server connection
socklen_t socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));
serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM1);
server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  code for for client connection 
// socket, connect, and recv here
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

 memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));
 client.sin_family = AF_INET;
 client.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
 client.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM2);

 connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(struct 
 sockaddr));

recv(client_socket, msg, MAXRCVLEN, 0);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// printf("As a client, I Received %s \n", buffer);
// memset(buffer, 0, strlen(buffer));

printf("Server starts...\n");

do{
listen(server_socket, 1);
consocket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
send(consocket, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
    while(len=recv(consocket, buffer, MAXRCVLEN, 0)>0){
            printf("Received: %s ", buffer);

// As a client, send "buffer" here

           send(client_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);


           if(strncmp(buffer, "exit", 4) == 0) break;


      memset(buffer, 0, strlen(buffer));

       }
printf("Goodbye !\n");
    close(consocket);

}while(consocket);

close(client_socket);
close(server_socket);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is my `client.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXRCVLEN 500
#define PORTNUM 2300
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 2500   //The port  to establish UDP connection

void DieWithError(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
exit(1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buffer[MAXRCVLEN + 1]; // for receiving
int len, mysocket;
struct sockaddr_in dest;
char msg[MAXRCVLEN + 1]; // for sending

mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
dest.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

connect(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//UDP initialization 
  struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;

  int s, i, slen = sizeof(si_other) , recv_len;
  char message[BUFLEN];
  //int num=0;
  char buf[BUFLEN];
 //create a UDP socket
 if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
{
    DieWithError("socket() failed");
}

// zero out the structure
memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

//bind socket to port
if( bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
{
    DieWithError("bind() failed");
}



//check digits or alpha



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
len = recv(mysocket, buffer, MAXRCVLEN, 0);
if(len < 0){
    perror("Reciver failed");
    close(mysocket);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
else{
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    printf("I Received %s \n", buffer);
 }


            //printf("Received: %s ", buffer);


 while(1){
    printf("Enter a character ");
    fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin);
    if(strncmp(msg, "exit", 4) == 0) break;
    if(send(mysocket, msg, strlen(msg), 0) < 0){
            perror("Send failed");
            close(mysocket);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

 memset(msg, 0, strlen(msg));

}
if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other,
&slen)) == -1 )//to receive message from server as UDP
    {
        DieWithError("recvfrom() failed");
    }
  printf("Received a packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr),
  ntohs(si_other.sin_port));
    printf("Data: %s\n" , buf);

 //printf("Received: %s ", buffer);    
 close(mysocket);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "I couldn't send a specific message to the client using UDP". Please describe more specifically what error or problem you encounter when you attempt to do that.

Comment: @ kaylum, When I test my code, if I type a message in client.c, client.c sends to the transfer.c and it will forward to the server.c, Wha I'm looking for is that, once server.c received the message from transfer.c it will check whether the received message is alpha or digit, if it is alpha it will send" this is not digit " to the client using UDP but if it is digit it will just forward received message. I have if(islpha) function to check that and  right after this function i have UDP sendto function. I think there is  error.

Comment: Don't just repeat yourself. Describe the *problem.* What happens? Nothing? Error? Computer explodes?

Comment: Indentation................

Comment: @ EJP It didn't give me any error, Just server receives the message and waits for more data.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think your coding style is good. And the follow could work.

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>      
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define PORTNUM 2400
#define MAXRCVLEN 500
#define SERVER "127.0.0.1" // local server
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 2500   //The port to establish UDP conection

void DieWithError(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* msg = "HI \n"; 
    char buffer[MAXRCVLEN + 1];

    int len, consocket;
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    struct sockaddr_in serv;
    int mysocket;
    socklen_t socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

    mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//UDP initialiazation to forward received message to client
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other), recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char message[BUFLEN];
    int num; //number of messages   

    s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

//creates socket
    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    inet_aton(SERVER , &si_other.sin_addr);


    /*{
        DieWithError("sendto() failed");
    }*/


 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    do{
        listen(mysocket, 1);
        consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
        send(consocket, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
            while((len=recv(consocket, buffer, MAXRCVLEN, 0))>0){
                if( strncmp(buffer, "exit", 4) == 0) 
                    break;

            buffer[len] = '\0';
                printf("Received: %s", buffer);
         //checks the received message alpha or digit
                memset(buf,0, BUFLEN);
                    if(isalpha(buffer[0])){
                    strcpy(buf, "this is not a digit");//sends this message to client 
        //if the message is alphs
                }
            else {
                    strcpy(buf, "this is a digit");//sends this message to client 
            }

            //puts(buf);

           //udp sends function to send the msg using UDP
                    if (sendto(s, buf, strlen(buf) , 0 , (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen)==-1)
                {
                    DieWithError("sendto() failed");
                }
    //clear the buffer
  //memset(buffer, 0, strlen(buffer));
        }

            close(consocket);

    }while(consocket);

    printf("Goodbye !\n");
    close(mysocket);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Transfer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>

#define PORTNUM1 2300
#define PORTNUM2 2400
#define MAXRCVLEN 500


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* msg = "HI from Inter-server\n"; 
    char buffer[MAXRCVLEN + 1];

    int len, consocket;
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    struct sockaddr_in serv;

    struct sockaddr_in client;

    int server_socket;
    int client_socket;

    // For server connection
    socklen_t socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM1);
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  code for for client connection 
    // socket, connect, and recv here
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    client.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM2);

    connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    recv(client_socket, msg, MAXRCVLEN, 0);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    // printf("As a client, I Received %s \n", buffer);
    // memset(buffer, 0, strlen(buffer));

    printf("Server starts...\n");

    do{
        listen(server_socket, 1);
        consocket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
        send(consocket, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
        while((len=recv(consocket, buffer, MAXRCVLEN, 0))>0){
            printf("Received: %s ", buffer);
    // As a client, send "buffer" here
            send(client_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
            if(strncmp(buffer, "exit", 4) == 0) 
                break;
            memset(buffer, 0, strlen(buffer));
        }
        printf("Goodbye !\n");
            close(consocket);
    }while(consocket);

    close(client_socket);
    close(server_socket);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXRCVLEN 500
#define PORTNUM 2300
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 2500   //The port  to establish UDP connection

void DieWithError(char *s)
{
        perror(s);
    exit(1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[MAXRCVLEN + 1]; // for receiving
    int len, mysocket;
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    char msg[MAXRCVLEN + 1]; // for sending

    mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    dest.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

    connect(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//UDP initialization 
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;

    int s, i, recv_len;
    socklen_t slen = sizeof(si_other);
    char message[BUFLEN];
  //int num=0;
    char buf[BUFLEN];
 //create a UDP socket
    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
            DieWithError("socket() failed");
    }

// zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

//bind socket to port
    if( bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
            DieWithError("bind() failed");
    }



//check digits or alpha



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    len = recv(mysocket, buffer, MAXRCVLEN, 0);
    if(len < 0){
            perror("Reciver failed");
            close(mysocket);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else{
            buffer[len] = '\0';
            printf("I Received %s \n", buffer);
    }


            //printf("Received: %s ", buffer);


    while(1){
        memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            printf("Enter a character ");
            fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin);
            if(strncmp(msg, "exit", 4) == 0) 
            ;
            if(send(mysocket, msg, strlen(msg), 0) < 0){
                    perror("Send failed");
                    close(mysocket);
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == -1 )//to receive message from server as UDP
            {
                DieWithError("recvfrom() failed");
            }
        printf("Received a packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port)); 
        printf("Data: %s\n" , buf);
    }
 //printf("Received: %s ", buffer);    
    close(mysocket);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I will check it and let you know, I know I'm not good in C, Most complicated one.

Comment: It worked perfectly, I made some stupid mistake, I realized. Thank you!